# How to Upload file to Firebase Storage using Firebase Admin in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-storage, blob, firebase-admin

I am trying to create a Firebase Admin Panel using Eclipse Java  for my Android Studio App and I want to be able to upload content(pdf, other files, etc) to Firebase Storage so that users can download this content through my app. Is there any way I can achieve this? 
I have tried using the code below to see if this will suit my need:

```
Bucket bucket = StorageClient.getInstance().bucket();

Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build()
                .getService();


BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucket.getName(), "folder");
System.out.println("Blob Id:"+blobId);
BlobInfo blobInfo = 
BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
System.out.println("Blob Info:"+blobInfo);
Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud 
Storage!".getBytes(UTF_8));
```

But..... I'm getting this NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:956)at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I can't seem to get much info about this...Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have all needed code to be sure, but it seems that you have variable `UTF_8` and it was not assigned. I suppose this should be String value "UTF-8".

If you want some refence I have found something like [that](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-getbytes-method-example/)

I hope it will help!

Comment: OMG! Bless you! It works like a charm!  Thanks you so much! =D